# Is there a Linux program to manage both brightness and contrast?

Tags: linux, display

I use Linux alongside Windows. On Windows, I use *Free Monitor Manager* to manage **both** brightness and contrast, but I haven't found any for Linux. I tried *Desktop Dimmer* on Linux and it works fine, but it allows me to manage brightness **only**. I use Kubuntu.

Comment: I'm not using KDE, hence only a pointer: [this forum thread at KubuntuForums](https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php/63622-adjusting-the-contrast-brightness-on-desktop) might help you. Also see, on our sister site: [How to change the constrast on ubuntu with terminal or using a KDE tool?](https://askubuntu.com/q/68397/68291) [This quora page](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-adjust-Ubuntu-17-04-brightness) also mentions some options for `xrandr` you might wish to use.

Comment: Perhaps [Flux](https://justgetflux.com/) might work?

Comment: Just in case you find the desired software yourself (eg. from the links above) and didn't know: be welcome to [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) then :)